# What is this syntax called?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out what the piece of code below means/does, and what this syntax is called in Typescript parlance? What does `[name: string]: string` mean?

```
export interface APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters {
  [name: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

> Edit
> Does it mean whatever type implements this interface needs to provide something like an array? or a map? e.g: typeA["str1"] = "str2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAUCSBxOkDucAnulAPYAeRAogG4Tjp4AWTUcAthJFAM7IBvAFDJkAbRCcIALmS8wUUAHMAurPmKQS5AB9kAVxAATCDFAQjAbiEBfIUJMIANnCgoEZEPOQAHV515ZDBw8CEIScio6BjAmMFZ-Lh5eayE-dg5eADpPCEtkAHoCuQVlXQNjU3MjNMTeMQByMHwyBpV8opLNbT1DEzMQC1qM+oBlIg4AIzInLLheIhAETB48Mih2wuLqKHIoWQAVIh8UBsNgAEd9FAWpmYbkBDgQEDIwZEmUfV4LZHm-kDIUAmCjIMDHCBZAAUACYAKwAZgAHABKIRAA)

```ts
interface APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters {
  [name: string]: string | undefined;
}

declare const params: APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters;

params.one; // string | undefined
params['two']; // string | undefined
params[Symbol.asyncIterator]; // Error: Type 'unique symbol' cannot be used as an index type.(2538)
```